# bootstrap tags input tag value is not submitting with form

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tags-input

Can someone explain what is going on here? I don't understand why the values that I submit in the tag input field are not being submitted with the form. I've tried this with [both examples](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)
and neither will send the values correctly.

I am using [bootstrap4-tagsinput](https://github.com/Nodws/bootstrap4-tagsinput.git)

HTML CODE:

```html
     <form class="needs-validation" action="/archive" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Solution Name</label>
            <input name="solution_name" type="text" class="form-control" required>
            <label>Vendor Name</label>
            <input name="vendor_name" type="text" class="form-control" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Attachment</label>
            <input name="file" type="file" class="form-control-file" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tags</label>
             <input class="form-select" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput">
          </input>
         </div>

         <button type="submit" value="upload" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Server

```py
@review_archive_host.route('/archive', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def archives():
    if "review_archive" not in session['u']['flags']:
        flash("You do not have permissions to access that feature/page")
        return redirect(get_redirect_url())
    #archive search page
    if request.method == "POST":
        #create a new archive record
        d = request.form.to_dict(flat=True) or {}
        return d
```

Example form and response:

[image]

response:

```json
{
  "solution_name": "asdfs", 
  "tags": "", 
  "vendor_name": "asfsd"
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer according to this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of the link you provided informs that this puglin was designed for Bootstrap `2.3.2` and `3`. By the tag of your question, I saw that you are using `4`.

And others people [having issues](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/672) using it on Bootstrap 4.

I uploaded a small example based on your form and method for [Github](https://github.com/wiltonsr/Bootstrap-Tags-Input), but using version `3` of Bootstrap and it worked as expected.

[image]

[image]

An alternative could be [this](https://github.com/Nodws/bootstrap4-tagsinput). They fix the compatibility problem with bootstrap 4 based on the plugin you used initially

`EDIT:`

After your answer's update using [Nodws/bootstrap4-tagsinput](https://github.com/Nodws/bootstrap4-tagsinput) I made a small test using this plugin and I was able to reproduce the problem.

When analyzing the `request.form` sent, I noticed that with this version of the plugin the key `tags` are coming in duplicate.

`ImmutableMultiDict([('vendor_name', u'vendor'), ('solution_name', u'solution'), ('tags', u''), ('tags', u'tag1,tag2')])`

Because of that you dont get any value when your route parser the form to dict.

I replicate your code with [this](https://github.com/vachigaggl/bootstrap-tagsinput) another version of plugin and now is working as expected.

[image]

The complete example continues on my [Github](https://github.com/wiltonsr/Bootstrap-Tags-Input).

Comment: the duplicate name is in fact what I was noticing, i didnt know why it was defaulting to the blank value.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin in the documentation is for bootstrap 2.3.2 or 3 and would not work for bootstrap 4.

In order to use that plugin, you could downgrade your bootstrap to version 3.

An alternative would be the Bootstrap 4 Tag Input Plugin With jQuery - https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-4-Tag-Input-Plugin-jQuery.html

Comment: This is the plugin that I am using.